# Description bug in DEB file created by jpackage when opened with QApt installer

Tags: java, deb, jpackage

Adding description with `--description` while creating deb package on linux creates deb file, which when opened with `QApt package installer` (double click installation) shows defined text in description section, which seems like a *bold header* and underneath there is that description again with first character stripped:

[image: example]

Command:

```
jpackage -t deb \
--app-version 1.0.0 \
--icon books256.png \
--name hello \
--description 'my testing text' \
--dest target/jpackage_outputdir/ \
--temp target/jpackage_tempdir \
--input target/jpackage_inputdir \
--main-class core.Main \
--main-jar jarfile.jar \
--linux-menu-group Office \
--linux-shortcut
```

Is there a way to prevent this *unprofessional* look by finely setting *bold header* and text underneath separately or at least by removing this duplication in description section?

Using Kubuntu 23.0.4, JDK - openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18 LTS

Comment: Seems to be a bug in QApt: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=986010 -- you can check that the description inside the package itself is ok by taking it apart using `ar x hello.deb` and looking at the control file.

Comment: @teapot418 I noticed that several deb packages from various vendors have this issue. However, I think i found _solution_ by using multiline description. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem might be to use multi-line description. First line is then bold text and second line is below it, altough bug still remains when using single-line description.

```
jpackage -t deb \
--app-version 1.0.0 \
--icon books256.png \
--name hello \
--description 'first line
second line' \
--dest target/jpackage_outputdir/ \
--temp target/jpackage_tempdir \
--input target/jpackage_inputdir \
--main-class core.Main \
--main-jar jarfile.jar \
--linux-menu-group Office \
--linux-shortcut
```

[image: solution]

**EDIT:**

This "fix" breaks desktop icon on Ubuntu (22.04). It is not shown under "Show applications" in gnome desktop.